# How to return back to My Application after completing the call from iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am showing contacts list in my iphone application. When user taps a contact number then call starts.
But when call is completed then  iPhone exits from My Application and switches to the Apple iPhone contacts application.

Please suggest me any idea on how to return back to My Application after completing the call..

Thanks
Deepika

Answer (score 5):

This is by design and your application will not be relaunched after the call terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, your app terminates and won't re-open.